# Google GCM onHandleIntent called repeated when no Internet connections

Tags: android, android-intent, google-cloud-messaging

I have followed https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/start and used https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services/tree/master/android/gcm/app/src/main/java/gcm/play/android/samples/com/gcmquickstart as a template for implemented GCM.

It worked fine when the app starts with Internet connection, however, if there is no Internet, my app gets caught in an infinite loop:

```
12-08 01:00:07.318 26039-27088/myapp E/RegIntentService: end of intent
12-08 01:00:07.327 26039-27090/myapp E/RegIntentService: onHandleIntent
12-08 01:00:07.339 26039-27090/myapp E/RegIntentService: Failed to complete token refresh
                                                                java.io.IOException: SERVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE
                                                                    at com.google.android.gms.iid.zzc.zzb(Unknown Source)
                                                                    at com.google.android.gms.iid.zzc.zza(Unknown Source)
                                                                    at com.google.android.gms.iid.InstanceID.zzc(Unknown Source)
                                                                    at com.google.android.gms.iid.InstanceID.getToken(Unknown Source)
                                                                    at myapp.services.RegistrationIntentService.onHandleIntent(RegistrationIntentService.java:49)
                                                                    at android.app.IntentService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(IntentService.java:65)
                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:211)
                                                                    at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
12-08 01:00:07.339 26039-27090/myapp E/RegIntentService: end of intent
12-08 01:00:07.355 26039-27091/myapp E/RegIntentService: onHandleIntent
12-08 01:00:07.368 26039-27091/myapp E/RegIntentService: Failed to complete token refresh
                                                                java.io.IOException: SERVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE
                                                                    at com.google.android.gms.iid.zzc.zzb(Unknown Source)
                                                                    at com.google.android.gms.iid.zzc.zza(Unknown Source)
                                                                    at com.google.android.gms.iid.InstanceID.zzc(Unknown Source)
                                                                    at com.google.android.gms.iid.InstanceID.getToken(Unknown Source)
                                                                    at myapp.services.RegistrationIntentService.onHandleIntent(RegistrationIntentService.java:49)
                                                                    at android.app.IntentService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(IntentService.java:65)
                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:211)
                                                                    at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
12-08 01:00:07.369 26039-27091/myapp E/RegIntentService: end of intent
```

Initially `onReceive` from `mRegistrationBroadcastReceiver` is also called multiple times but later it stops from being logged.

My Activity:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
    mRegistrationBroadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            Log.e(TAG, "onReceive");
        }
    };
    if (checkPlayServices()) {
        // Start IntentService to register this application with GCM.
        Log.e(TAG, "Start RegistrationIntentService");
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, RegistrationIntentService.class);
        startService(intent);
    }
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(mRegistrationBroadcastReceiver,
            new IntentFilter(QuickstartPreferences.REGISTRATION_COMPLETE));
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).unregisterReceiver(mRegistrationBroadcastReceiver);
    super.onPause();
}
```

My RegistrationIntentService:

```
 @Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    Log.e(TAG, "onHandleIntent");
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    boolean sent = sharedPreferences.getBoolean(QuickstartPreferences.SENT_TOKEN_TO_SERVER, false);
    if (sent) {
        return;
    }

    try {
        // [START register_for_gcm]
        // Initially this call goes out to the network to retrieve the token, subsequent calls
        // are local.
        // R.string.gcm_defaultSenderId (the Sender ID) is typically derived from google-services.json.
        // See https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/start for details on this file.
        // [START get_token]
        InstanceID instanceID = InstanceID.getInstance(this);
        String token = instanceID.getToken(getString(R.string.gcm_defaultSenderId),
                GoogleCloudMessaging.INSTANCE_ID_SCOPE, null);
        // [END get_token]
        Log.e(TAG, "GCM Registration Token: " + token);

        sendRegistrationToServer(token);

        // Subscribe to topic channels
        subscribeTopics(token);

        // You should store a boolean that indicates whether the generated token has been
        // sent to your server. If the boolean is false, send the token to your server,
        // otherwise your server should have already received the token.
        sharedPreferences.edit().putBoolean(QuickstartPreferences.SENT_TOKEN_TO_SERVER, true).apply();
        // [END register_for_gcm]
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Failed to complete token refresh", e);
        // If an exception happens while fetching the new token or updating our registration data
        // on a third-party server, this ensures that we'll attempt the update at a later time.
        sharedPreferences.edit().putBoolean(QuickstartPreferences.SENT_TOKEN_TO_SERVER, false).apply();
    }
    // Notify UI that registration has completed, so the progress indicator can be hidden.
    Intent registrationComplete = new Intent(QuickstartPreferences.REGISTRATION_COMPLETE);
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(registrationComplete);
    Log.e(TAG, "end of intent");
}
```

What's the cause of this?

Comment: are you registering and unregistering `mRegistrationBroadcastReceiver` in `onResume` and `onPause`?

Comment: @Blundell yes, I have.

Comment: Also I think you should be checking for internet before `sendRegistrationToServer`, right now GCM throws an `IOException` and you catch this in `Exception` which is gross - you then send a `REGISTRATION_COMPLETE` broadcast anyway ... even though it was a fail

Comment: put a log in `onCreate` does that get called multiple times?

Comment: @Blundell I understand those may not be the best practice (though it is in the sample code Google provides), but how does catching the exception or sending the broadcast cause the service to run repeatedly?

Comment: @Blundell nope, `onCreate` only gets called once.

Comment: yeah they don't I was just trying to narrow down the possible issues. What if you comment out the code after the catch block, i.e. the `LocalBroadcastManager.sendBroadcast` , struggling to see an issue with the code you've posted...

Comment: @Blundell I still couldn't find the cause of the problem but I managed to bypass it using your suggestion of checking Internet connection in the beginning of `onHandleIntent` and calling `return` immediately if no Internet is available.